# 6 white and 6 black balls in 10 urns, without empty urns

Tags: combinatorics

6 white and 6 black balls of the same size are distributed among 10 urns so that there is at least one ball in each urn. What is the number of distributions of balls?

Comment: Are the urns distinguishable or indistinguishable?

Comment: All are similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint/outline:

Case 1: One urn has $3$ balls and each of nine urns has one ball.  In this case, there are four possibilities, all based on the balls in the urn with $3$ balls: WWW, WWB, WBB, BBB. (Since the urns are indistinguishable, we don't differentiate between which urns get which of the remaining colors.)

Case 2: Two urns each have $2$ balls and each of eight urns has one ball.  As in the previous case, you just need to determine the number of possible distributions for the urns with more than $1$ ball.

---

Update for distinguishable urns:

Let's look at a couple of cases:

Case: Suppose we have an urn with WWB and $9$ urns with one ball:

Choose an urn for three balls: $10$ ways.

Choose $4$ of remaining $9$ urns each for $1$ white ball: ${9\choose 4}$ ways.

Total for this case: $10\cdot{9\choose 4}$ ways.

Case: Suppose we have an urn with WW and an urn with WB and eight urns with one ball each:

Choose an urn for WW ($10$ ways)

Choose a remaining urn for WB ($9$ ways)

Choose $3$ of remaining $8$ urns for a white ball (${8\choose 3}$ ways).

Total for this case: $10\cdot 9\cdot {8\choose 3}$ ways.

Note: Try to work out the other cases similarly.

Comment: But @paw88789 the answer given is 26250. I understood your hint but am unable to proceed further.

Comment: This suggests that perhaps the urns are distinguishable after all. From your earlier answer to my question, I presumed the urns were indistinguishable.